# How to record on development environment

Tags: ringcentral, call-recording

I am struggling to record calls on the development environment; automatic call recording is not available and I can't initiate manual recording. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would direct your attention to the [Call Control API](https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-reference#Call-Control-Beta-startCallRecording), specifically the call recording options. Access to these APIs may require you to have them enabled for your account. Couple these APIs with event subscriptions alerting you of new calls, and one could effectively auto-record every call.

Answer (score 1):

The find the similar type of question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53702142/how-to-record-on-development-environment/56623219#56623219)

The RingCentral mobile app as I can see does not support sandbox mode. But still you can use the RingCentral soft phone and switch the soft phone to sandbox mode before login with your sandbox credentials.

**On Windows:** Ctrl + F2
**On Mac OS:** Fn + Command + F2

If you wish to create call recordings programmatically, there is an GitHub app that will help you:

https://github.com/anilkumarbp/Sample-Demo-to-Download-Call-Recordings

other source you can refer: https://developers.ringcentral.com/guide/call-log/manual/recordings

ref from similar question: https://forums.developers.ringcentral.com/questions/1367/how-to-enable-call-recording-in-sandbox-environmen.html